# Global Vector & Push_Back

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have a class called `GameObject` and I am trying to store instances of itself into an `std::vector` called `gameObjectList` by `push_back` function in `GameObject` constructor.

**GameObject.h**

```
class GameObject;

static unsigned int gameObjectCount = 0;
namespace {
    static std::vector<GameObject> gameObjectList;
}

class GameObject {

public:

    Transform transform;

    std::string tag;
    std::string name;
    unsigned int objectID;

    bool active = true;

    GameObject findGameObject(std::string Name);
    std::vector<GameObject> findGameObjectsWithTag(std::string Name);

    void Update();
    void addComponent(Component component);
    Component getComponent(std::string type);
    std::vector<Component> getComponents(std::string type) const;

    void setActive(bool value);

    GameObject(std::string Name = ("GameObject" + gameObjectCount), Transform transform = Transform());

private:

    std::vector<Component> mComponents;
};
```

**GameObject.cpp**

```
#include "../Headers/gameobject.h"

GameObject::GameObject(std::string Name, Transform transform)
{
    tag = "default";
    name = Name;
    objectID = gameObjectCount;
    mComponents.push_back(transform);
    this->transform = transform;

    gameObjectCount++;
    gameObjectList.push_back(*this);
}
```

I have this header file included into my `engine.cpp` and I want to be able to access the `gameObjectList` to do things like this for example:

**Engine.cpp (extract)**

```
#incldue "../Headers/engine.h"

void Engine::run()
{
    if (this->init() != 1)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "[SYS] Couldn\'t Initialise Engine" << std::endl;
        shutdown();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "[SYS] Engine Completely Initialised!" << std::endl;

    mState = EngineState::RUNNING;
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(mWindow.getWindow()))
    {
        /*OpenGL stuff here*/

        this->update();

        std::cout << int(gameObjectList.size()) << std::endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < (int)gameObjectList.size(); x++)
            gameObjectList[x].Update();

        glfwSwapBuffers(mWindow.getWindow());
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "[SYS] !-------------------!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[SYS] Shutting Down Engine" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[SYS] !-------------------!" << std::endl;
    shutdown();
}
```

*(Engine.h includes GameObject.h)*

I have triggered breakpoints trying to follow how it all plays out and when I am in the constructor, it successfully adds the `GameObject` to the `std::vector`, but as soon as you are out of the constructor its almost as if the entire vector erases itself because the size and contents all go back to `0`. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong, and want I should be doing to be able to access this vector globally.

Comment: You need to show us the rest of the code.

Comment: I thought that would be satisfactory but I'll quickly edit it all up

Comment: When a `GameObject` inserts itself into the list, do you intend that other code using the list will access the original object (which inserted itself) of a copy of it?    Do you intend that every compilation unit will have it's own distinct list, or that all compilation units share a single list between them?

Comment: I just wanted to have one list which I could access all of the GameObjects which have been created from my GameObject and Engine header and source files @Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide the full code, especially the code of the destructor. Thus I only guess your problems.

The code below inserts a copy of the game object into the vector. I am sure, that is not what you want.

```
gameObjectList.push_back(*this);
```

You should refactor your code, probably like below.

```
static std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjectList;
// ...
gameObjectList.push_back(this);
```

**UDATE** After OP pasted the full code.

Anonymous namespace and static global in .h is useless.

```
namespace { static std::vector<GameObject> gameObjectList; }
```

It makes each .cpp having own and defferent `gameObjectList` from others. In one .cpp you add new element into vector, another .cpp has own empty vector.

You should declare the vector in .h

```
extern std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjectList;
```

And define it in one and only one of .cpp

```
std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjectList;
```

Instead of using `extern` the better is declare it `static` class member.

Comment: I tried doing that before but I got like 20 errors that I couldn't be bothered to refactor to suit the pointer of GameObject in the vector, I was asking to see if I didn't need to do that but I guess I'll try doing it now.

Comment: @Sharpie See my update. And yes, above the update is still actual.

Comment: @S.M. `extern` is what OP wants, see comment to question

Comment: I just declared it as a static in the header file and then defined it without the static accessor in the gameobject cpp file, and made all the changes with std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjectList but still the same results

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl Thank you. I thought about static class member. Updated my answer.

Comment: Agree on `static` in the class. Also recommend a factory function to do the construction so that you do not have to add to the list inside the constructor. You can add in the factory. Copying constructing while inside another constructor is kinda gross

Comment: Yeah I was confused just then with the static declaration with the definition in the cpp file, thanks @MatthäusBrandl

Comment: Everything works how I want now, thank you for the support with my idiotic practices and I will try using a factory function @user4581301 thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @Sharpie Also note that having a global vector with all your instances is a global static. That is a perilous path to take as more and more code will depend on that which makes testing really hard. This is just one problem of your design as it stands. The next thing that strucks me is that `GameObject findGameObject(std::string Name);` seems to operate on the global albeit being a member of your class.

Comment: @Sharpie: separate that stuff into a (e.g.) `GameObjectInventory` class. If you must you can still have a singleton of that type, but it would be better to pass a reference (or pointer) to classes and functions needing it. That way you adhere more to the single responsibility principle plus gain testability.

Comment: @LuboAntonov Raw pointers might be the right tool, depending on the semantics of that vector. (ownership vs. reference)

Comment: Not enough info to make the call on whether or not pointers should be in this game at all. I think there may be a case for using `std::map` if the number of `GameObject`s is large and you do a lot of look-ups.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl thank you for pointing out the problem with findGameObject, I was just drafting these ideas of a gameobject franework this afternoon and the code I made was just very rough and very bad code written in like 20mins, just trying to create a small usable class for the short term and refactor it later, thanks for all the pointers and recommendations guys! Shines great insight into how I can better improve my coding practices.